# Kibana visualization of Winlogbeat sending sysmon data of launch time application of the application

Tags: go, kibana, elastic-stack, metricbeat

in the kibana dashboard, winlogbeat records the sysmon event and send it to elasticsearch and henceforth to kibana. there are 3 field name on time basis and i am not able to understand the difference between them namely event_data.PreviousCreationUtcTime, event_data.UtcTime and event_data.CreationUtcTime.[in the below link, it's kibana visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okXRN.png)

[image]

Comment: Not  a powershell question. Removing tag

Comment: Not a go question either